# How to add custom Visual Studio debug view of Python object?

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, natvis

I'd like to add a useful visualization of a Python `openpyxl` `ReadOnlyCell` object during debugging in Visual Studio 2015 (Python tools). I read into [`natvis` files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects), but they seem to be only for C++ projects. For example, the screenshot below shows what a ReadOnlyCell looks like in the Autos window. I'd like to display the `value` property (e.g. 6000 for cell 0 below) in the column, without having to navigate into each cell individually.

There seems to be a way to add Python object visualization by editing the [`PythonDkm.natvis` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode). I have found the file, but I don't understand how to add a custom class to the it. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I didn't find the information which support python, but I will discuss with other members, if I get any information, I will share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `__repr__` on your `ReadOnlyCell` class. That is what is displayed first, and then you can expand to see the rest of the values.

For example:

```
class ReadOnlyCell:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}(value={self.value})"
```

Would be displayed as:

```
Name     Value                           Type
[0]      ReadOnlyCell(value=6000)        ReadOnlyCell
```

---

Aside: the `PythonDkm.natvis` file is for mixed Python/C debugging. It contains the natvis definitions for viewing raw Python objects, and has no impact on regular Python debugging.

Comment: Conversely, `__repr__` is for Python-only debugger - if mixed native/Python debugging is used, it provides its own repr for those types that it knows of, and a hardcoded generic representation (type name + address) for everything else.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you Zooba. For those looking for exact steps: Delete cached files in `<python>\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl`, edit `<python>\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\read_only.py` to include the `__repr__` function (I just used `return str(self.value)`). Probably not best practice to directly edit libraries installed with `pip`, but having this quick representation of a cell really helps.